# Redirect links from old on prem SharePoint to new SharePoint Online when old environment no longer exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, iis, redirect

Did a migration from on-prem SharePoint to SPO. Users have documents with hard-coded links to old on-prem SharePoint environment. When user clicks this old link, what is best way to redirect them to new destination in SPO ?

The old on-prem SharePoint env is gone.

Old link - http://sharepoint.companylan.local/sites/sitename/...
New link - https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/...

I have access to IIS servers on our network to try redirect to SPO, looking for more details on this process, if it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it may be impossible to redirect a document link to a new link in SharePoint on-premises. If you want to redirect a SharePoint page, it can be achieved via injecting JS code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
alert("This application has been moved to replaced with another version, please update all existing bookmarks.  You will be redirected momentarily.");
// ]]>
</script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10";url="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx">
```

See this thread: [SharePoint 2013 redirect Siteto another site in SPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165612/sharepoint-2013-redirect-siteto-another-site-in-sp).

But to redirect a document link directly, I'm afraid it is impossible.